# how to extract child path in ksh93

Tags: ksh

I can do it in ksh88 as this

```
path="/a/&b/c/d"
parent="/a/&b"
child="${path#$parent/}"
```

but cannot in  ksh93 
What's the syntax to do the same when the substring containing a slash?

Comment: When you know the substring is without a `#`, you can use `child=$(echo "$path" | sed "s#^parent/##")`.

Comment: There is nothing to modify, your script works with `ksh` (`ksh88`) and both the original `ksh93` and modern releases of `ksh93`.

Comment: @jlliagre Sorry about that. The case is actually with double quotes as my paths contain some annoying characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that should work in all cases unless the path contains a <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> character (BELL).

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH
path="/a/&b/c/d"
parent="/a/&b"
sep=$(printf "\07") # or \033 to use ESC instead of BELL
child="$(printf "%s" "$path" | sed "s$sep^$parent$sep$sep")"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Does the 1st line add the path of sed? Why do you pick Esc as the separator?

Comment: The first line put POSIX versions of utilities in first position in the PATH, especially `sed` here indeed. This might help in some OSes. The separator was supposed to be \007 to match the description but \033 would be equally fine, assuming this character doesn't appear in the path.